Python+Selenium. Page wan't load in headless mode
I'm trying load page with that code
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://www.chabad.org/calendar/zmanim_cdo/aid/143790/locationid/790/locationtype/1/save/1/tdate/4-15-2024/jewish/Zmanim-Halachic-Times.htm')
    try:
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'group_4/15/2024')))
        print("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")


and I get a TimeoutException. But if I run browser in standard mode (not headless) it works fine.
Because I need get information from page on the server, I want run browser in headless mode. So how can I load information from that page?

That site blocks regular Selenium headless mode, but you can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase in UC Mode + Headless Mode to get around the limitation.
pip install seleniumbase, and then run with python:
import re
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, headless=True) as sb:
    sb.open('https://www.chabad.org/calendar/zmanim_cdo/aid/143790/locationid/790/locationtype/1/save/1/tdate/4-15-2024/jewish/Zmanim-Halachic-Times.htm')
    sb.click("button#button1")
    sb.click("span#month")
    sb.click('div[value="12"]')
    sb.click('[date*="12/31"]')
    text = sb.get_text_content("div.group.active_date")
    text = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', text).strip()
    print(text)

Expected output:
Dawn (Alot Hashachar)
3:34 AM
Earliest Tallit and Tefillin (Misheyakir)
4:37 AM
Sunrise (Hanetz Hachamah)
5:50 AM
Latest Shema
9:19 AM
Latest Shacharit
10:31 AM
Midday (Chatzot Hayom)
12:54 PM
Earliest Mincha (Mincha Gedolah)
1:31 PM
Mincha Ketanah (“Small Mincha”)
5:06 PM
Plag Hamincha (“Half of Mincha”)
6:36 PM
Sunset (Shkiah)
8:00 PM
Nightfall (Tzeit Hakochavim)
8:40 PM
Midnight (Chatzot HaLailah)
12:53 AM
Tuesday
Shaah Zmanit (proportional hour)
71:42 min.

The script lets you set the date you want.
